# Pasting names to an object during lapply

Tags: r

Consider this code:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(9),3,3))   
names(df) <- c("A","B","C")
y <- c(1,2,3)
list1 <- lapply(df, function(x) as.vector(x))
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
lapply(list1, function(x) plot(x,y))
```

I want to paste the name of each vector in list1 (A, B, C) to the x-axis of the respective x,y-plot.
Can i do it during lappy, or is it necessary to write a loop?

Comment: you can't do it with `lapply` but you could use `mapply` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using 'lapply', while iterating over names:

```
lapply(names(list1),function(nn){
  plot(list1[[nn]],y,ylab=nn)
}
)
```