# pasting names of list-objects into a ggplot call during lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of ggplot-objects

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
plots <- list(p,p,p)
names(plots) <- c("A","B","C")
```

which i can manipulate:

```
plots <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme_bw())
grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]], plots[[3]])
```

This works fine. However, what i cannot do is pasting the names of the ggplot-objects into the `ggtitle`-argument:

```
plots <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + ggtitle(paste(names(x))))
grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]], plots[[3]])
```

Something, was pasted into the argument, but I basically missed the correct  hierarchy level:

```
grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]], plots[[3]]) ### all titled "data"
names(plots[[1]][1])
[1] "data"
```

Moving up the hierarchy does not work:

```
plots <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + ggtitle(paste(names(plots[[x]]))))

 Error in plots[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I remembered an [old question of mine for base-R plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523078/pasting-names-to-an-object-during-lapply), but this is was not possible to transfer here:

```
plots <- lapply(names(plots), function(x) plots[[x]] + ggtitle(paste(names(x))))
names(plots)
NULL
```

Where did i fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution using `Map`:

```
# Your sample plots
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
plots <- list(p,p,p)
names(plots) <- c("A","B","C")
plots <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme_bw())

# Add title to ggplots
plots <- Map(function(gg, title) gg + ggtitle(title), plots, names(plots));
grid.arrange(grobs = plots);
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. If you try to ggsave that grid.arrange output, does it save only the last plot in plots?

Comment: @nouse You can use `ggsave(file = "...", arrangeGrob(grobs = plots))` to save all three plots. While `grid.arrange` draws to a device, `arrangeGrob` returns a `grob`, which can be saved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you loose the names of the list you iterate over with `lapply`.

if you check

```
lapply(plots, function(x) browser())
```

then you will see that `names(x)` returns

```
[1] "data"        "layers"      "scales"      "mapping"     "theme"       "coordinates" "facet"      
[8] "plot_env"    "labels"
```

One way of adding titles iteratively would be to iterate over an index and use that to subset `plots` and `names(plots)`:

```
plots <- lapply(seq_along(plots), function(i) { 
  plots[[i]] + ggtitle(names(plots)[i])
})
```

Then, a title will be added, e.g. for `plots[[1]]`:

[image: output]

Comment: The `Map()` solution is more elegant though!

Answer (score 1):

Adding another option using `cowplot::plot_grid` which I found helpful.

```r
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plots, 
                   labels = names(plots),
                   ncol = 1)
```

[image]

---

Data

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
plots <- list(p,p,p)
names(plots) <- c("A","B","C")
plots <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme_bw())
```